# R only returns last value and other's NA

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to Create a new variable that is the mean of parent and child height（ (parent[1]+child[1])/2）,...,((parent[928]+child[928])/2）. I put in a for loop (the question asked me to do that instead of just using rowMeans).

```
`
for (i in length(galton$parent)) {
  g_mean<-c()
  g_mean[i]<-(galton$parent[i]+galton$child[i])/2
  g_mean<-c(g_mean,g_mean[i])

  return(g_mean[i])
}

`
```

My code is like this, But it gives me a variable full of NA...
I don't know why.

Comment: You are overwriting your g_means in every loop with `g_means <-c()`. also, you don't need  `g_mean<-c(g_mean,g_mean[i])`. Lastly, you can do this without the loop. `g_means <- (parent + child)/2`. you can do the math with the vectors.

Comment: Besides what @AndS. wrote, `for (i in length(galton$parent))` loops one iteration only, `i in length(.)`, not `i in 1:length(.)`

Comment: Oh!! R can automatically add up each row and make a new vector without the loop !! It's good to know that!! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the mean of the parent and the mean of child or the mean of the sum of them?

Comment: the mean of the sum of them for each row

Comment: This clarifying question is better posed as a comment rather than an answer.